# Python Django return unique save dates and filter model objects

Tags: python, django, filter, save, models

I have two models

Room and RoomLog

each single Room object can have multiple RoomLog objects.
the purpose of it is that Room object has got an attribute: value and method save(). I create a new related RoomLog object every time a user saves changed attribute of any specific Room object and saves it.

RoomLog object has got value attribute and date attribute.
date is related to Room save method so it gives Room changed value save DATE.

My question is:

Q1: How to return all unique days from all RoomLog objects so I know when any save took place ?

Q2: Let's say we know how to return unique days. So, the question is: how to select any day from these unique days and display all Room objects values by chosen date ? I would like to return last saved value from chosen date for each Room object.

The way I tackle both questions at the moment (I am looking for more Pythonic, faster, better performing solutions) is:

I created Form in which I iterate through RoomLog objects:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    roomdates = []
    roomextracted = []
    for r in RoomLog.objects.all():
        if r not in roomdates:
            roomdates.append(r.update_date)
    for i in roomdates:
        if i not in roomextracted:
            roomextracted.append(i)

    ROOMDATA = [(r, r) for r in roomextracted]
    my_choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ROOMDATA)
```

then I have a view to pass selected date to another view in which I filter Room.objects.all() by selected date:

```
def choices(request):

    form = RoomLogChoices()
    form.fields['choice'].choices = list()
    testlist = []
    for rl in RoomLog.objects.all():
        if rl.update_date not in testlist:
            testlist.append(rl.update_date)
    for d in testlist:
        form.fields['choice'].choices.append(
                (
                    d,d
                )
        )


    return render(request, 'prostats/choices.html', {'form':form})
```

next I have choicesform.html in which I select date from dropdown menu:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post" >
{% csrf_token %}

<ul>
{% for choice in form.my_choice_field.field.choices %}
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="my_choice_field" value="{{choice.0}}"
      {% if equal form.my_choice_field.data choice.0 %}
         checked="checked"
      {% endifequal %}/>
    <label for="">{{choice.1}}</label>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

and this is the view in which I handle POST data

```
class AllRoomsView(ListView):
    template_name = 'prostats/roomsdetail.html'
    queryset = Room.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):


        context = super(AllRoomsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['rooms'] = Room.objects.all()
        context['rlog'] = RoomLog.objects.all()



        roomsdates = []

        for r in context['rlog']:
            if r not in roomsdates:
                roomsdates.append(r.update_date)

        roomextracted = []
        for i in roomsdates:
            if i not in roomextracted:
                roomextracted.append(i)

        context['roomextracted'] = roomextracted
        choicedate = self.request.GET.get('choice')
        if choicedate != None:
            choosend = choicedate
        else:
            choosend = '2016-02-01'



        #filtered rlogs
        rlfilteredempty = []
        for r in context['rooms']:
            i = RoomLog.objects.filter(room=r.id, update_date__lte = choosend).order_by('-update_date')[:1]
            if i:
                rlfilteredempty.append(i[0])
            else:
                rlfilteredempty.append(r)
        context['rlfiltered'] = rlfilteredempty




        context['choicedate'] = self.request.GET.get('choice')
        #context['roomfiltersettime'] = RoomLog.objects.filter(update_date__lte = choosend)
        context['roomfiltersettime'] = RoomLog.objects.filter(update_date__lte = choosend)

        rslice = []
        for r in context['rooms']:
            i = RoomLog.objects.filter(room=r.id, update_date__lte = choosend).order_by('-update_date')[:1]
            if i:
                for rsobject in i:
                    rs = (r.flat.flat_number,r.flat.block.block_name,r.room_name)
                    rl = rsobject.id
                    rv = rsobject.room_value
                    rslice.append((rs,rl,rv))
            else:
                rs = (r.flat.flat_number,r.flat.block.block_name,r.room_name)
                r = r.id
                rslice.append((rs,r))

        context['rslice'] = rslice
```

So, all of it what I have done I feel is not very good and maybe somebody can point me with some good ideas on how to tackle this problem better ?

---

EDIT: update of the post with my Room and RoomLog models:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length= 10)
    room_value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    flat = models.ForeignKey(Flat)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add= True)
    created_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add= True)
    substage_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Room, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.value_original = self.room_value

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            response = super(Room, self).save(**kwargs)
            if self.value_original != self.room_value:
                room_log = RoomLog()
                room_log.room = self
                room_log.room_value = self.value_original
                room_log.save()
            return response



class RoomLog(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
    room_value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    update_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add= True)
    update_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add= True)
```

Answer (score 0):

To return all unique days, use `distinct()` on your `created_date` field. That will, of course, only work if `created_date` is actually a *date* and not a datetime value!

```
RoomLog.objects.all().distinct('created_date')
```

If your `created` value is a `datetime`, you need to make it a date first, using Django's `func()` and `F()` functions. That uses the `DATE()` SQL functions that may not work on all databases, but it does on Postgres and probably many others.

```
RoomLog.objects.all()\
       .annotate(created_date=Func(F('created'), function='DATE'))\
       .order_by('-created_date')\
       .distinct('created_date')
```

Only a partial answer. The second question depends on the layout of your models that you didn't post.

Comment: Hi, it all works fine (I mean just .distinct() without a need to .annotate().order_by().disctinct. Thanks PS. I have just edited the post and added models.